# How to choose the fields for a Send Relationship in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fields, send-an-email

I don't understand what a Send Relationship is in Marketing Cloud, its purpose and how to determine which fields need to be included into the Send Relationship. For example if one field is a Subscriber Key, then how do I know which one needs to be the second field?

The explanation in the Trailhead is confusing and doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is very confusing indeed.

Data Extensions have very high degree of freedom in configuration, in contrast to lists, which are always fixed in the way that they e.g. have an email field and a subscriber key field. The standards of a list help the system understand what is IN the fields without the user needing to make any configuration.

Data extensions don't have a standard, you set them up however you want. Which is great, but in order for the system to work, you need to explain to the system how your data extension data should be treated. The linchpin here is that the system needs to understand *what field identifies a person* in your DE.

This is relevant when your DE is meant to be sendable because at the time of sendout the system needs to write some of this information into data views (statistics tables) like _Sent using that identifier.

Send Relationship basically does that. It tells the system:

"In this DE the field that identifies a person is called ______first box ______. For all intents and purposes, e.g. when sending, please treat the content of this field as the system-internal entity of ______ second box _______."

There are two options for the second box.
Subscriber KEY means that a key is used that can be set by an external system, which is the case in probably 99+% of implementations. For example in a Setup with Marketing Cloud connect, the external system Sales Cloud provides the keys, typically conctact Ids from Sales Cloud.

Subscriber ID is an SFMC-internal key that no other system is meant to understand, and it is also not meant to be shared, as it could be easily spoofed. Since one point of a key is to interact with other systems, likely you don't want Subscriber ID.

If you do not know what you should be doing here, then it is PROBABLY key. I for one have never even seen a system where this was set up with "Subscriber ID" and I would be hard-pressed to construct a fitting usecase.

Note that the Send Relationship does not have to be primary key. So it *does not have to uniquely* identify persons, the same person (as defined by a Send Relationship) could be in your DE multiple times.

A typical setup looks like this:

```
Send Relationship:
subscriberKey relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key
```

in plain english:

```
"In this DE the field that identifies a person is called subscriberkey. 
For all intents and purposes, e.g. when sending, please treat the content of this field as the system-internal entity of Subscriber Key."
```